# pytest discovery misses decorated methods

Tags: python, pytest, python-decorators

I want to be able to write a bunch of tests in a format similar to this:

```
class TestPytest:
    @given(3)
    @expect(3)
    def test_passes(self, g, e):
        assert g == e

    @given(3)
    @expect(4)
    def test_fails(self, g, e):
        assert g == e

    def test_boring(self): # for comparison
        pass
```

(I'm not convinced this is a good idea, but I'll be taking it in further directions, so it's not as strange as it looks.)

To that end, I've attempted to write these decorators:

```
import functools

class WrappedTest(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.func = f
        self.given = []
        self.expects = []

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        @functools.wraps(self.func)
        def call(*a, **kw):
            return self.func(instance, self.given, self.expects,
                             *a, **kw)
        return call

def given(*objects):
    def wrapped(test):
        if not isinstance(test, WrappedTest):
            test_tmp = WrappedTest(test)
            test = functools.update_wrapper(test_tmp, test)

        test.given.extend(objects)
        return test
    return wrapped

def expect(*objects):
    def wrapped(test):
        if not isinstance(test, WrappedTest):
            test_tmp = WrappedTest(test)
            test = functools.update_wrapper(test_tmp, test)

        test.expects.extend(objects)
        return test
    return wrapped
```

But when I try to run this test, pytest doesn't find `test_passes` or `test_fails`. It does find `test_boring`.

My working hypothesis is that I haven't properly wrapped the test methods. They show up as functions rather than methods:

```
>>> test_pytest.TestPytest().test_fails
<function test_pytest.test_fails>

>>> test_pytest.TestPytest().test_boring
<bound method TestPytest.test_boring of <test_pytest.TestPytest instance at 0x101f3dab8>>
```

But I'm not sure how to fix this. I've tried changing `functools.wraps(self.func)` to `functools.wraps(self.func.__get__(instance, owner))`, under the theory that it would then wrap with a bound method rather than a function. But that was kind of a guess, and it didn't work.

I know pytest is capable of finding decorated functions written properly, so presumably I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I was wrong about wrapping. Looking through the pytest source, it treats nested classes differently from methods. It accesses members through `__dict__`, which ignores `__get__`, so `WrappedTest` wasn't successfully pretending to be a method.

I've replaced the `WrappedTest` instance with a function, and it seems to be working fine (even without the `@functools.wraps` line):

```
import functools
from collections import namedtuple

def wrap_test_method(meth):
    if hasattr(meth, '_storage'):
        return meth

    Storage = namedtuple('Storage', ['given', 'expects'])
    sto = Storage(given=[], expects=[])

    @functools.wraps(meth)
    def new_meth(self, *a, **kw):
        return meth(self, sto.given, sto.expects, *a, **kw)
    new_meth._storage = sto

    return new_meth

def given(*objects):
    def decorator(test_method):
        new_test_method = wrap_test_method(test_method)
        new_test_method._storage.given.extend(objects)
        return new_test_method

    return decorator

def expect(*objects):
    def decorator(test_method):
        new_test_method = wrap_test_method(test_method)
        new_test_method._storage.expects.extend(objects)
        return new_test_method

    return decorator
```